# Запятая перед союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед союзом "и"? Если нужно, то в каких случаях?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Запятая перед союзом "и" ставится в двух случаях:

- при перечислении каких-либо однородных членов предложения, каждый из которых имеет союз "и".
  *И швец, и жнец, и на дуде игрец.*
- если союз "и" разделяет две части сложносочиненного предложения.
  *Прилетели птицы, и на деревьях начали распускаться цветы.*

Comment: Таких случаев больше,чем два.

Comment: Во втором случае,наверное, имелось в виду "сложные предложения" (ССП и СПП)

Answer (score 9):

Случаев постановки запятой перед сочинительным союзом «И» отнюдь не мало:

- Во-первых, запятая ставится при повторении союза «И» при однородных членах предложения, например:

> ...и машины, и велосипеды, и самокаты

- Во-вторых, запятая ставится в сложносочинённых предложениях:

> Машина подъехала, и мы зашли внутрь к водителю.

Существуют также случаи, когда запятая перед «И» не ставится ввиду наличия общего второстепенного члена предложения, наличия вводного слова, наличия общего придаточного предложения:

- Общее придаточное предложение:

> Когда приехал Женя, я крикнул ему и он подошел к нам.

- Общий второстепенный член предложения (когда? — зимой):

> Зимой мы приехали в Петербург и к нам подселился Женя.